# pyspark concat multiple columns with coalesce not working

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The below code throws Column not iterable error.

**code:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('abcd', '123')], ['s', 'd'])
df.select(concat_ws('', coalesce(df.s, "sometext"), coalesce(df.d, "sometext")).alias('sd')).show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat_ws` expects the separator as first argument, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws). So if you do not want to use a separator, you could do:

```
df.select(concat_ws('',df.s, df.d).alias('sd')).show()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Basically i need to use `coalesce` each column inside `concat_ws` if the value is null and give some default value, i will change my question.

Comment: please check now, if this possible or not

Comment: I think you could do `df.select(F.concat_ws('', F.coalesce(df.s, F.lit("sometext")), F.coalesce(df.d, F.lit('hi'))).alias('sd')).show()` since the functions expects columns. Please refrain from changing your question in the future; it is better to close one question if it is resolved and open a new one for your new question. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: @Florian, I have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295160/pyspark-mapping-variables-from-different-dataframes Thanks in advance!